# Android NDK broken includes

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to include GStreamer to my jni folder. But all dependencies are broken. For example

```
#include <glib.h>
```

Should be replaced with

```
#include <../../../include/glib-2.0/glib.h>
```

I'm using gradle-experimental 0.7.2

My app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {

android {
    compileSdkVersion = 24
    buildToolsVersion = "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig.with {
        applicationId = "com.sizyntsev.cpplearning"
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 16
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
    }

}

android.buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-rules.pro"))
    }
}

android.ndk{
    moduleName "gstreamer"
    cppFlags.add("-I ${new File("src/main/jni/gstreamer_lib/include/glib-2.0/glib.h").absolutePath}".toString())
}

}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cppFlags.add("-I ${new File("src/main/jni/gstreamer_lib/include/glib-2.0/glib.h").absolutePath}".toString())
```

You should pass path to directory, not the path to file itself. Also you can inspect generated intermediate `Android.mk`. Just look into `build/intermediates/ndk`.